# SQL to aggregate cost with different column than the one reported by

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
PROJECT   EMPLOYEE  TASK  COST
A        SCOTT      p    500.00
A        EMILY      Q    400.00
B        PETER      K    125.00
B        PETER      R    125.00
C        JOHN       Y    200.00
C        JOHN       Z    200.00
```

I need to create SQL view (Oracle Database 11g -11.2) where the out put is as follows:

```
PROJECT EMPLOYEES    TASK   COST
A       SCOTT, EMILY  P,q  900.00
B       PETER         K, R  125.00
C       JOHN          Y, Z  200.00
```

Note the difference in cost reporting - if the resource is different the add up the cost, if same then do not add up the cost. So the cost in the table is not by task it is by the employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `listagg()`:

```
select project,
       listagg(employee, ', ') within group (order by cost desc) as employees,
       listagg(task, ', ') within group (order by cost desc) as tasks,
       sum(cost)
from t
group by project;
```

EDIT:

You have a lousy data structure, but:

```
select project,
       listagg(employee, ', ') within group (order by cost desc) as employees,
       listagg(task, ', ') within group (order by cost desc) as tasks,
       sum(case when seqnm = 1 then cost end) as cost
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by project, employee order by cost) as seqnum
     from t
    ) t
group by project;
```

Comment: This one works perfectly for the listagg part, however, the sum(cost) part double counts the cost, see my latest comment on GMB's answer which also has weakness when there is three records for two different employees.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Linoff,  for taking the time and post the solution for me, It made my week.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation. To compute the `cost`, you can compare its `min()` and `max()` to see if there are at least two distinct values:

```
select
    project,
    listagg(employee) within group (oder by cost desc) employees,
    listagg(task) within group (oder by cost desc) tasks,
    case when max(cost) = min(cost) then min(cost) else sum(cost) end cost
from mytable
group by project
```

Comment: This almost works however, if there is two different employees in the same project but one of the employee worked on two different tasks, it actually sums all of the rows by project. For example, in Project B, Emily also worked with cost of 200.00, then the above SQL sums the total cost as (125+125+200) where as it should be (125+200), is there any way to avoid that?